# Combine DataTrigger and Trigger in a MultiDataTrigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, triggers

I've seen from some examples that it is possible to combine this kind of trigger:

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
```

With this kind of data trigger :

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsHighlightable}" Value="True" />
```

By using a MultiDataTrigger like this:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True"/>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsHighlightable}" Value="True" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#BF6DBDD1"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedItemBackgroundBrush}"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

However, this does not work with attached properties. This trigger works:

```
<Trigger Property="UI:TreeViewHelper.IsMouseDirectlyOverItem" Value="True">
```

But this does not work:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=UI:TreeViewHelper.IsMouseDirectlyOverItem}" Value="True"/>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsHighlightable}" Value="True" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#BF6DBDD1"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedItemBackgroundBrush}"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

Is there a way I could make the trigger work correctly inside the MultiDataTrigger? The IsMouseDirectlyOverItem property was taken from here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/21/mytreeviewhelperismousedirectlyoveritem.aspx.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx) for attached properties is different:

```
Path=(UI:TreeViewHelper.IsMouseDirectlyOverItem)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsHighlightable}" Value="True"/>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#BF6DBDD1"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedItemBackgroundBrush}"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```